# Elasticsearch score with subdocuments count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have these 3 objects (3 users with photos, and every photo has a category id)

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User1",
    "photos":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "cat": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "cat": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "cat": 2
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "User2",
    "photos":[
        {
            "id": 4,
            "cat": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "cat": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "cat": 2
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "User3",
    "photos":[
        {
            "id": 7,
            "cat": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "cat": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "cat": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to give a score (max score: 10) to these documents depending on how many photos they have with cat = 1

```
Object1 : 2 objects with cat = 1
Object2 : 1 objects with cat = 1
Object3 : 0 objects with cat = 1
```

So the score will be Object1 = 10, Object2 = 5, Object3 = 0

Comment: Can you preprocess the documents before indexing them in Elasticsearch and add a cat1 field for example with counts of cat = 1 photos (or the scores you want)?  And then you can simply sort on this field instead of getting bogged down with scoring and scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Either what @eemp said or if you cannot modify the way documents are indexed and/or if you cannot modify the mappings, then one solution would be to leverage a [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) with a [`script_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score) component in which we access the `photos` array and multiply by 5 the number of elements having `cat == 1` .

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_source.photos.findAll{return it.cat == 1}.size() * 5"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get the scores you expect, i.e.

- 10 for object 1
- 5 for object 2
- 0 for object 3

Comment: I'm doing something like that right now... But the reason I start this topic is the max score... You simply multiply every photo with 5.... So the score can increase more than 10...

I want the max score to be always 10..

If a user has 100 photos with cat = 1..... his score will be between 0-10 (depending how much photos the others users have)

Comment: So you want your scores to always be within the [0,10] interval?

Comment: Note that you can always normalize the score on the client side since you'll get `max_score` and the `_score` for each document, so the formula in your client should be as simple as `10 * hit._score / max_score`